# Is there any way to restore an entire previous version of a folder in an s3 bucket?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know folders are not folders within S3, but it would be extremely useful if you could restore a previous version of one when you have versioning enabled. I've been looking at it and I can only see previous version of files, not folders.

If you have a folder with thousands of files and a hundred of them were deleted and you are not sure where or when exactly this is extremely useful.

Is there any way to do this?

(Using Linux)

EDIT:

It looks like the only way to do this efficiently is to use this tool:

https://labs.madisoft.it/amazon-s3-point-in-time-restore/

I am shocked that the official s3 tools and s3cmd don't support this.

Comment: Company behind the tool actually resigned from maintenance, so the tool was moved to the original author github https://github.com/angeloc/s3-pit-restore. Disclaimer: I'm the original author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already given a correct response to your own question.
You told that "folders are not folders within S3" and this is true. Furthermore, there is NO folders in S3, just keys which are just sequences of characters.
Most of the software treats '/' character as a delimiter of folders. E.g., "a/b/c" is treated as file "c" in folder "b" which is, in turn, in folder "a".
 There have been another approach. I know, some software used to treat the "$folder$" string as a delimiter. But the '/' character looks like much more natural for most people.
Now back to versions of folders. No folders - no folders restore.

Sergio, CloudBerry Lab

Comment: Yes I figured that much. I just wished they somehow camed up with a way to have several snapshots of folders as it would be an enormously useful feature... Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

A quick search for this came up with this below for the same question on stack overflow:

AWS CLI

```
aws s3 ls s3://<bucket_name> | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -L 1 aws s3api restore-object --restore-request Days=<days> --bucket <bucket_name> --key
```

s3cmd

```
s3cmd restore --recursive s3://mybucketname/folder/
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033651/how-to-restore-folders-or-entire-buckets-to-amazon-s3-from-glacier

Regards

Liam

Comment: That's not exactly what I asked, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Would that not work though as it'd restore a whole *folder* to x days ago. Which is what you're wanting to do?

Comment: On second look, I guess this not only applies to glacier as I thought it would (I don't really use glacier unless it is implicitly used by versioning) I could give it a shot. Is it just me or most things in Amazon are considerably more complicated than they need to be? ;-)

Comment: I'm the same, I don't use it or a less it's used by versioning. I think it comes across as them being complicated but is actually down to them using the fastest logic, such as storing key/value instead of maintaining a hierarchy as sorting by name will auto give you the entire structure in order anyway. I love AWS though, I've designed and implemented our entire website architecture on, which we have over 1million users a year use and we've had next to no issues (other than a huge DDOS attack).